# How can I insert data before running karate tests?

Tags: spring-boot, karate

I have some dummy data in sql file `testdata.sql` and I need to run this script before I run the karate tests? what is the best way to do that? I am using spring boot and java

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [Karate and Spring Boot / Database](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/database/README.md) example.

This sample has a `schema.sql` file in `src/test/java` or the root of the test classpath. Spring boot [will use this when the application starts](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql). You can easily add SQL statements to insert data. You may need to do some research on how to mix your default schema and data in your SQL file.

Otherwise I recommend write a small Java utility to connect to your DB after the app starts and fire off the SQL statements. The Karate Spring / Database example should give enough pointers on how to do that.

Comment: Peter please point to documentation, it is unclear how to setup run config for a single feature file. It is clear how to run JUnit config and all the feature files under specific folder, it is also clear how to run single feature file from JUnit by specifying path to that single file. Now instead of JUnit config I want to run single.feature config by pressing green run button in .feature file (I am using Intellij and payed PRO version of Karate). I need to spin the server right? what else?

Comment: @IamMashed the green-run button will only run a karate test. if you need to start a server automatically when the test starts, then it is better you use a junit runner like this one (right-click and run as junit test): https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/database/src/test/java/karate/DogsTest.java

Comment: so what is the point of paying PRO subscription if green-run button in a feature file does not spin server automatically? 
i mean it is again huge hustle of spining localhost server manualy, then populating database again manually and only then green-run button in a feature will work and perform proper testing.
i can not hit breakpoints in a feature file if i run JUnit configuration, that is why i payed for PRO version for the hope of a faster developement process. was my hope a false one?

Comment: yes, I think you are expecting too much. even if we focus only on spring, every project starts servers very differently, some use docker, etc. this is where the excellent integration of karate and java is useful. I suggest you pair up with someone on the dev or dev-ops side, and write a simple junit runner. once this is created, you can connect all your karate tests to it. since karate supports a java style run-configuration in intellij, you may be able to use that to specify what to run before starting a karate test.

Comment: thank you Peter for clarification. we have a junit runner that spins docker database container and we have a script that populates it and all feature files are successfully run from junit function. This way we do not have that cool option to set breakpoints in .feature files for debugging. see what I mean?

Comment: noted. we will work on adding this very shortly so stay tuned. to be clear - you are saying is that you want to be able to debug karate tests even when you initiated a test via a java runner, correct ?

Comment: Thank you Peter for your reply. i want to be able to debug .feature files. i.e need to be able to set breakpoints in .feature files when initiated via java Junit class runner. Any chance I can track this feature?

Comment: @IamMashed yes you can track it here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-intellij-plugin/issues/44